# Good patterns or apps to use when writing django code that will serve multiple, subtly different sites

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

I'm heading into working on a project that will be a single codebase that will manage multiple, slightly different sites. I've found a few things, which I'll put in the answers, but I'd like to see if people have other ideas, especially for how to manage the minor form, model, and view differences that crop up.

Comment: Will the sites differ in functionality or in appearance/branding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping for better answers, but I wanted to put these in here in case I don't get them, or to give people looking for the same info the few links I've found. =)

http://www.huyng.com/archives/franchising-running-multiple-sites-from-one-django-codebase-2/394/

and

http://blog.uysrc.com/2011/03/23/serving-multiple-sites-with-django/